# Merge Two solr core into One

Tags: apache, tomcat, solr, solrj, solrcloud

I have two solr cores namely Unit1 and Unit2 with the same schema for both.Now I have created a new core called Unit and I want to copy/move the data from unit1 core and unit2 core into Unit core .
Thanks in advance for the replies/answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can call the below :

```
admin/cores?action=MERGEINDEXES&core=new-core-name&indexDir=path/to/core1/data/index&indexDir=path/to/core2/data/index
```

for more details on the same you can refer [Merge Indexes](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/coreadmin-api.html#CoreAdminAPI-MERGEINDEXES) link.

Comment: I have already did it but it says that people with less than 15 reputation cant vote .